# Android Scroll View space in the bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-scrollview

I want a help for design a screen.. I want to make a details screen, with a picture and a text (scrollabe).. But when i test, the text doesnt fill all the space...Its puts a empty space at the bottom of the text... How can i fill all the layout with the text?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.rs.app.paginas.antena_detalhe">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="495dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgAntena"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@mipmap/baloon" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitulo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Nome" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDetalhes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:scrollbars="vertical" />
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

and the screen:

[image]

Comment: why you have given layout height and width to linear layout?

Comment: this the android studio put automatic...

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer if it was useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change to "match_parent" in your first LinearLayout´s height and widht parameters to fill all the screen, cause the parent in this case is your phone' screen, but if you define values in dp as shown in your code (495dp) then it´ll fill just that dimensions, and the screen dimensions change with every phone and his own screen size, that´s why it works in some little screen devices, and with bigger screens probably wont do it, the best solution to make it work with every screen size is changing your code like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.rs.app.paginas.antena_detalhe">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"           
        android:layout_height="match_parent"          
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    ...
```

Hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

You should change from:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.rs.app.paginas.antena_detalhe">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="368dp"
            android:layout_height="495dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.rs.app.paginas.antena_detalhe">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout you have defined fixed dimensions for your linear layout which contains your scroll view and other widgets. I would suggest changing your root layout to Linear Layout with maximum width and height :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
tools:context="com.example.rs.app.paginas.antena_detalhe">
```

And remove the child linear layout.

Reason you were getting extra space was because of fixed height,which may be not present on phone with lesser height.